# Getting warning Unreachable Code Detected

Tags: c#

this is my code which generate warning for `flag = false;`

```
public bool Check_Contact(string username)
{
    bool flag=false;
    bool str;
    IEnumerator enumerator = this.All_Contacts_dt.Rows.GetEnumerator();
    try
    {
        do
        {
            str = enumerator.MoveNext();
            if (str)
            {
                DataRow current = (DataRow)enumerator.Current;
                str = !(current["Username"].ToString() == username);
            }
            else
            {
                flag = false;
                return flag;
            }
        }
        while (str);
        flag = true;
        return flag;
    }
    finally
    {
        IDisposable disposable = enumerator as IDisposable;
        str = disposable == null;
        if (!str)
        {
            disposable.Dispose();
        }
    }
    flag = false;
    return flag;
}
```

what is the problem in the code? thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `flag = false;` will indeed never be reached. Your `try` block ends with a return. So the possibilities are:

- Your code is executed successfully so that the `return` statement ist reached. The method is exited after the `finally` block has run.
- There is an exception before the `return` statement. The `finally` block is run and the exception is handed to the calling method until a matching `catch` block is found.
- There is an exception in the `finally` block. The execution of the block is stopped and the exception is handed to the calling method until a matching `catch` block is found.

So in any case, `flag = false;` will not be reached.

Answer (score 4):

The only way the code's execution leaves your `try` block is through its `return` statements, which means that any code following your `finally` block will never be executed.

```
try
{
    // ...
    return flag;   // Control returns to caller here (after executing finally block).
}
finally
{
    // ...
}

// Execution never reaches this point.
flag = false;
return flag;
```

Comment: "break;" statement will do the same; however, in this case, the code after the finally statement will be reachable.